# Fatal error: Class 'BaseController' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have created a controller menus.php which extends basecontroller as follows

```
<?php
class Menus extends BaseController {
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }
}
?>
```

and BaseController.php in application/core folder as follows

```
<?php
class BaseController extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
?>
```

I m getting error as **Fatal error:**  Class 'BaseController' not found in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class file name must begin with "MY_" unless you've changed it in config.php.

```
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
```

https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html

Hope this helps.